# Дополнительные символы в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Имеется код регулярки: `/^[^.][\w\s-.\,!\?()]+[^.]/iu`, но данный код не читает такие символы, как: `0\/|=+@$#%^&*"№;:?'<>`, как сделать так, чтобы он их начал читать?

Comment: `\s-.` очень странно выглядит, ибо \s означает любой пробельный символ, а не сам пробел и использование его в качестве начала интервала непредсказуемо, лучше использовать сам пробел. А интервал 'пробел-.' по идее должен дать много символов, но не все. Посмотрите таблицу ASCII http://www.asciitable.com/ что бы задать верные интервалы или перечислите символы по одному

Comment: Может стоит отталкиваться от набора символов, которые _не должны_ входить в символьный класс?

Comment: Ну можно и так, но вся суть в том, что я без понятия, как убирать пробелы в текста, а именно - если текст передан пустым (То есть - просто нажали кнопку отправить, поставили пробелы или-же использовали команду alt + 0160 и т.п, но не сам текст) Если такая регулярка вообще есть, которая проверяет такое, был бы благодарен, если дадите.

Comment: @in1, так что именно вам нужно? убрать все пробелы из строки? так ваше регулярное выражение не осуществляет никаких замен, только проверяется соответствие шаблону. т.е., результат — не строка «без пробелов», а «да» или «нет».

Comment: Мне оно и нужно, к примеру, пользователь отправляет сообщение, пустое, с пробелами - сообщение проверяет регулярка, если все гуд, то отправляет сообщение, если нет - то ошибка.